# static_cast redirects to multiple classes having the same function even though it is cast to a single class? Why does this work?

Tags: c++, static-cast

I am using asynchronous C++ GRPC in which I receive a `void*` pointer to an object, in this case it could correspond to instances of classes `MapCall` or `ReduceCall`. Each of these classes has the function `void Continue()`. When I receive the object I static_cast the pointer to a `MapCall` object. 
The cast though correctly casts to the correct class and calls the correct `Continue`  method even though I explicitly cast to a particular class. No error is thrown as well.

I have provided the class and function declarations and the code calling it.

```
class Worker {

    public:

        Worker(std::string ip_addr_port);

        void HandleRpcs();

    class MapData
        {
         public:
            MapData(MasterWorker::AsyncService* service, ServerCompletionQueue* compl_cq, Worker* parent)
            :service_(service), compl_cq_(compl_cq), map_status_(SLEEP), responder_(&ctx_), parent_service_(parent) {

                is_done = false;
                Continue();
            } 
           virtual void Continue(){ ...
           }
}
    class ReduceData
        {
         public:
            ReduceData(MasterWorker::AsyncService* service, ServerCompletionQueue* compl_cq, Worker* parent)
            :service_(service), compl_cq_(compl_cq), map_status_(SLEEP), responder_(&ctx_), parent_service_(parent) {



            virtual void Continue(){ ...
            }
      }
}
```

And the `HandleRpcs()` casting and calling it

```
void Worker::HandleRpcs() {

    mr_flag_=1;

    new MapData(&service_, call_cq_.get(), this);
    new ReduceData(&service_, call_cq_.get(), this);

    while(1){
      void* call_tag;  
      bool call_ok;

      call_cq_->Next(&call_tag, &call_ok );
      GPR_ASSERT(call_ok);

      // if (mr_flag_)
      static_cast<MapData*>(call_tag)->Continue();  
      // else
        // static_cast<ReduceData*>(call_tag)->Continue();  

    }

  }
```

Comment: If `call_tag` doesn't actually point to a `MapData` object, you have *undefined behavior*. Static type-casting is done at compile-time, and there's no way for the compiler to check that a `void*` is pointing to what you claim it it pointing to in the cast, so it can't warn if its not.

Comment: I also suggest you rethink your design, so you don't have to use `void*`. Inheritance, virtual functions and polymorphism is probably a better way to make sure things work as they should.